# [root@pcm-ipa-01 tmp]# klist klist: No credentials cache found (ticket cache FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0)freeipa kadmin admin principal not found

Tags: linux, centos, kerberos, freeipa

I have installed freeipa on centos and after restarting the service seems to have lost authentication for "kadmin"

```
[root@pcm-ipa-01 ~]# kadmin init
Authenticating as principal root/admin@MY.DOMAIN T with password.
kadmin: Client not found in Kerberos database while initializing kadmin interface
```

however I can authenticate directly with the user "admin"

```
[root@pcm-ipa-01 ~]# kadmin -p admin
Authenticating as principal admin with password.
Password for admin@MY.DOMAIN: 
kadmin:  list_principals
get_principals: Operation requires ``list'' privilege while retrieving list.
kadmin:
```

update:

```
[root@ipaserver tmp]# ipa user-show admin
ipa: ERROR: did not receive Kerberos credentials


[root@pcm-ipa-01 tmp]# klist
klist: No credentials cache found (ticket cache FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what exactly do you need?

You should use IPA CLI instead of kadmin.
http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/FreeIPA_Guide/Kerberos_Errors.html

Comment: thanks, however ipa command fails as it cannot get Kerberos credentials...

Comment: Does "kinit admin" work?

Comment: no does not work....

Comment: What is the error you getting from command "kinit admin"?

Comment: yeah :) thats what i forgot to do first, also set the umask to 0022 and everythings back normal now...